# Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext : Operation failed

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-site-recovery

Below script works for one recovery vault but fails for another.

**Script**

```
$Sub = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName ''
$context = $Sub | Set-AzContext
$rv = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName '' -Name ''
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $rv -defaultprofile $context
```

**Error**

```
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext : Operation failed.
Download vault credential file using cmdlet Get-AzRecoveryServicesVaultSettingsFile and Import-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultSettingsFile
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $rv -defaultprofile $con 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.SiteRecover
```

Comment: Could you please add `-debug` into Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext and run the command `Resolve-AzError` to get error message in detail?

Comment: Hi, I am working on this error . It seems to be an Permission issue. I will keep you all posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the issue was related to vnet configuration. now it is resolved.

error was was coming as data was not passing from one vnet to another.